# Get value from text field and store it as array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, arrays, forms

I have a text field in my database called departments where i want to store the list of departments. The user will enter the name of departments with comma separation. For example:

```
department1, deaprtment2, department3
```

I want this value to be stored as array when the user submits the form. Also, i want the list of departments to show as a drop-down. Finally, while updating the table , the department field should also be editable as before(update by entering texts separated by commas).

**EDIT:**
I have added this to my model:

```
class Org < ActiveRecord::Base
   serialize :department, Array
   attr_accessible :name, :department
   before_validation :update_department
   validates :name, presence: true
   def update_department
     if department_changed? and department.is_a?(String)
        self.department = self.department.split(',').collect(&:strip) 
    end
  end
end
```

and the view:

```
<%= f.text_area :department, :cols => "10", :rows => "10" %>
```

now Whenever i try to sign up, the department field already has [] present and when i try to update the department is already ["[department1", "department2]"].

I want [] to be removed while signing up and only department1, department2 to show up when updating.

Please Help.

Comment: You should `serialize :departments, Array` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711334/string-to-serialized-array )

Comment: @MrYoshiji: I have edited my question. Can you please provide some further solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this would be via your models. I am assuming that you have a model called Org and another called Department and that you have defined a has many relationship between the two. All you then need to do is in your Org model add the following code:

```
  def department_list
    departments.collect { |d| d.department_name }.join(', ')
  end

  def department_list=(text)
    if id && text
      departments.destroy_all
      text.split(',').each do |d|
        departments.create(department_name: d.strip.capitalize)
      end
    end
  end
```

Then in your view add a text box using @org.department_list.

EDIT:

Based on your expanded question, you have department field in an org model that you want to store and show as an array and but edit as a simple text field. My thoughts on this was that I don't like the idea of storing department data a field in org, it is a one to many relationship so department should be a separate model. I would remove the department field from org. Then create a migration to create a departments table. It should look something like this:

```
class CreateDeparments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :departments do |t|
      t.integer :org_id
      t.string :department_name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Next in the Department model add this line of code:

```
belongs_to :org
```

In the org model add the following:

```
  has_many :departments, dependent: :destroy

  def department_list
    departments.collect { |d| d.department_name }.join(', ')
  end

  def department_list=(text)
    if id && text
      departments.destroy_all
      text.split(',').each do |d|
        departments.create(department_name: d.strip.capitalize)
      end
    end
  end
```

In your controllers and views you now have the following:

```
@org = Org.first
# List of departments as an array for a select
@org.departments
# A comma separated string for text boxes
@org.department_list
```

The department_list method can now be used to display the list in a text box and also be used to post and changes back. So you your view code just becomes this:

```
 <%= f.text_area :department_list, :cols => "10", :rows => "10" %>
```

You will probably need to amend your org controller by changing the create to something like this:

```
 def create
    @org = Org.new(params[:org])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @org.save
        @org.department_list = params[:org][:department_list]
        format.html { redirect_to org_url,
                      notice: "#{@org.name} was successfully created" }
        format.json { render json: @org,
                      status: :created, location: @org }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @org.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
 end
```

If you are still stuck I have a complete webiste on github that you can look through. For you it is orgs and departments and on mysite it is people and skills or people and credits. This is the link:

https://github.com/davesexton/CKCASTING

Comment: Actually i have the department field inside my model called org. What should i modify?

Comment: The following error shows up while rendering the sign up form: `uninitialized constant Org::Department`

Comment: Actually that was my mistake, i had written the name of model as departments.rb when it should be department.rb. Thanks for your great help till now. Now i have only one last thing, when i sign up the department is not created instead it is only created when i update it. Please help.